# 400 Error - Google API Stored Session Tokens? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api

Having trouble when going from development to production environment where something is wrong with my access tokens? Not 100% sure. Sorta new to some of this stuff. I'm thinking somewhere I need to reset the tokens or something? If I go to accounts.google.com and remove the app from my account and authorize my app again everything works.

This seems the problem code based on errors but I'm not positive.

```
def self.refresh!(refresh_token)
    conn = Faraday.new('https://accounts.google.com') do |conn|
      conn.request  :url_encoded
      conn.response :json
      conn.response :raise_error
      conn.response :logger unless Rails.env.production?
      conn.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    response = conn.post('/o/oauth2/token', {
      grant_type:    'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token,
      client_id:     Settings::KEYS['OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'],
      client_secret: Settings::KEYS['OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET']
    })

    body = response.body

    body['access_token'] if body['access_token']
  end
```

Any direction or explanation on how the auth happens would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate set of client ID and client secret for your production and development?

Comment: Yah. Already had them separated.